# Rebasing feature branch onto 'master' branch resulting in loss of pushed changes in the feature branch

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase

I was working on a feature branch called 'featureBranch' and made all the changes that I had to. I rebased my branch onto 'master', committed and pushed my feature branch to raise a merge request with the 'master' branch. The merge request was merged but due to some pipeline failures after my branch was merged, my manager reverted my changes.

I fixed the issues on my 'featureBranch', committed and then pushed the changes. Since I forgot to rebase my 'featureBranch' onto 'master', I rebased it after pushing my changes and now my changes were gone from 'featureBranch'. I did a hard reset and got my changes back but now I am not able to rebase my 'featureBranch' onto 'main' without losing my changes. I need to rebase because it is necessary that we resolve all the conflicts before raising the merge request.

What can I do to rebase my 'featureBrach' onto the 'main' branch without losing my changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as below steps:

1. Remember your commit hash (named C1) that fixed the issue.
2. Reset featureBranch to the commit point where you've merged.
3. Rebase or just pull the latest changes from the master branch.
4. Cherry-pick the commit C1.

Comment: 1. Do not remember — mark it with a transient branch or tag. 5. Remove it after.

Comment: @Pylon I don't understand point 2. Commit point where I have merged?

Comment: The point where the feature branch has ever been merged to the master branch.

Comment: How can I find that commit point?

Comment: See all your commit logs in the feature branch. The previous one of C1 should be.